# Extract a string array of names from JSON

Tags: c#, json, twitch

How can I extract the `viewers` from the following JSON to an array like `string[] people`?

```
{
  "_links": {},
  "chatter_count": 7,
  "chatters": {
    "moderators": [
      "moobot"
    ],
    "staff": [],
    "admins": [],
    "global_mods": [],
    "viewers": [
      "dzoomal94",
      "holeder",
      "koza1258",
      "kuba45209",
      "ufolud321",
      "varuulia"
    ]
  }
}
```

JSON is taken from here: https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/lempiank/chatters

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: At the very least, please copy the JSON into your post rather than just linking to it. This means if the link one day breaks, future readers will still be able to make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you can do it like this:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
string[] people = jo.SelectToken("chatters.viewers").ToObject<string[]>();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lSXrUR